# Event when Xamarin ListView BindingContext item changes

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is is possible to get an event when an item in the collection bound to a Xamarin Forms listview changes?
For example my object has a Date field which is bound to a label in a ViewCell. I would like an event fired when the Date is changed. Our object implements INotifyPropertyChanged so the listview updates properly.
I can manually subscribe to the OnPropertyChanged event of each item but I'm hoping their is an easier way.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are triggers in Xamarin.Forms. It seems like an event trigger will do what you need. For example:

```
<EventTrigger Event="TextChanged">
    <local:NumericValidationTriggerAction />
</EventTrigger>

public class NumericValidationTriggerAction : TriggerAction<Entry>
{
    protected override void Invoke (Entry entry)
    {
        double result;
        bool isValid = Double.TryParse (entry.Text, out result);
        entry.TextColor = isValid ? Color.Default : Color.Red;
    }
}
```

You can find more information about triggers [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/triggers/)

See this example for deleting an object when it is selected from a list view.

```
private MyItemsViewModel _myItemsViewModel;

private void MyItemsListView_ItemSelected(object sender,    SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyItem item = (MyItem)e.SelectedItem;

    if (item == null)
        return;

    // remove the item from the ObservableCollection
    _myItemsViewModel.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: Can this be used on a ViewCell in a bound ListView ?

Comment: What I need to do is remove an item from the bound collection once Date has a certain value.

Comment: It should if the object is bound correctly as you will have access to it on the event handler. See the example on the edit for when an element is selected from a ListView